# При запуске одной и той же программы, разные результаты построения поверхности

Tags: lisp, autocad

Не могу понять, пробовал обнулять mas и lin, но не работает(а иногда и правильно строит).
Если строить по отдельности то все корректно.

```
    ;//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ;//Функція визначення координати точки кривої Бізьє 2 порядку//
    ;//point1 перша точка                                        //
    ;//point2 друга точка                                        // 
    ;//point3 третя точка                                        //
    ;//temp параметр (0 <= temp <= 1)                            //
    ;//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    (defun bez2(point1 point2 point3 temp)
        (setq xx (+ (* (car point1) (expt (- 1 temp) 2)) (* 2 (car point2) temp (- 1 temp)) (* (car point3) temp temp)))
        (setq yy (+ (* (cadr point1) (expt (- 1 temp) 2)) (* 2 (cadr point2) temp (- 1 temp)) (* (cadr point3) temp temp)))
        (setq zz (+ (* (caddr point1) (expt (- 1 temp) 2)) (* 2 (caddr point2) temp (- 1 temp)) (* (caddr point3) temp temp)))
        (setq ptr (list xx yy zz))
    )
    ;//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ;//Функція побудови сітки поверхні                           //
    ;//mas_point масив точок знайдений за формулою Кунса         //
    ;//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    (defun my3DMesh (mas_point)
        (setq N (length mas_point)
              M (length (car mas_point))
        )
        (Command "3dmesh" M N)
                (setq n1 0)
                (repeat N
                        (setq m1 0)
                        (repeat M
                                (Command (nth m1 (nth n1 mas_point)))
                                (setq m1 (+ m1 1))
                        )
                        (setq n1 (+ n1 1))
                )
    )
    ;//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    (defun kyns(r1 r2 r3 r4)
        (setq r00 (car r1)
              r01 (car r3)
              r10 (car r2)
              r11 (caddr r3)
              ) 
        (setq v 0)
        (setq mas nil)
        (setq h 0.1)
        (repeat 11
            (setq u 0)
            (setq lin nil)
            (repeat 11                  
                (setq x (-
                            (+
                                (* (car (bez2 (car r4) (cadr r4) (caddr r4) v)) (- 1 u))
                                (* (car (bez2 (car r2) (cadr r2) (caddr r2) v)) u)
                                (* (car (bez2 (car r1) (cadr r1) (caddr r1) u)) (- 1 v))
                                (* (car (bez2 (car r3) (cadr r3) (caddr r3) u)) v)                  
                            )

                            (+
                                (* (car r00) (- 1 u) (- 1 v))
                                (* (car r01) (- 1 u) v)
                                (* (car r10) u (- 1 v))
                                (* (car r11) u v)
                            )
                        )
                )
                (setq y (-
                            (+
                                (* (cadr (bez2 (car r4) (cadr r4) (caddr r4) v)) (- 1 u))
                                (* (cadr (bez2 (car r2) (cadr r2) (caddr r2) v)) u)
                                (* (cadr (bez2 (car r1) (cadr r1) (caddr r1) u)) (- 1 v))
                                (* (cadr (bez2 (car r3) (cadr r3) (caddr r3) u)) v)                 
                            )

                            (+
                                (* (cadr r00) (- 1 u) (- 1 v))
                                (* (cadr r01) (- 1 u) v)
                                (* (cadr r10) u (- 1 v))
                                (* (cadr r11) u v)
                            )
                        )
                )   
                (setq z (-
                            (+
                                (* (caddr (bez2 (car r4) (cadr r4) (caddr r4) v)) (- 1 u))
                                (* (caddr (bez2 (car r2) (cadr r2) (caddr r2) v)) u)
                                (* (caddr (bez2 (car r1) (cadr r1) (caddr r1) u)) (- 1 v))
                                (* (caddr (bez2 (car r3) (cadr r3) (caddr r3) u)) v)                    
                            )

                        (+
                                (* (caddr r00) (- 1 u) (- 1 v))
                                (* (caddr r01) (- 1 u) v)
                                (* (caddr r10) u (- 1 v))
                                (* (caddr r11) u v)
                            )
                        )
                )
                (setq pointl (list x y z)
                      lin (cons pointl lin)
                )
                (setq u (+ u h))
            )
            (setq lin (reverse lin)
                  mas (cons lin mas)
            )
            (setq v (+ v h))
        )       
        (setq mas (reverse mas))
        (my3DMesh mas)
    )

    (command "erase" "all" "")
    ;//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ;//Визначення опрних точок поверхні                          //
    ;////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
    ;Палуба
    (setq p1 (list 0 0 0)
          p2 (list 7 7 0)
          p3 (list 25 2 0)
          p4 (list 25 0 0)
          p5 (list 25 -2 0)
          p6 (list 7 -7 0)
          p7 (list 0 0 0)
          p8 (list 0 0 0)     
    )
    (setq l1 (list p1 p2 p3)
          l2 (list p3 p4 p5)
          l3 (list p7 p6 p5)
          l4 (list p1 p8 p7)
    )

    (kyns l1 l2 l3 l4)
    ;Задній борт
    (setq p11 (list 25 2 0)
          p21 (list 25 3 -3)
          p31 (list 25 0 -5)
          p41 (list 25 -3 -3)
          p51 (list 25 -2 0)
          p61 (list 25 0 0)
          p71 (list 25 2 0)
          p81 (list 25 2 0)   
    )
    (setq l11 (list p11 p21 p31)
          l21 (list p31 p41 p51)
          l31 (list p71 p61 p51)
          l41 (list p11 p81 p71)
    )
    (kyns l11 l21 l31 l41)
    ;Лівий борт
    (setq p12 (list 0 0 0)
          p22 (list 7 -7 0)
          p32 (list 25 -2 0)
          p42 (list 25 -3 -3)
          p52 (list 25 0 -5)
          p62 (list 20 0 -10)
          p72 (list 0 0 0)
          p82 (list 0 0 0)    
    )
    (setq l12 (list p12 p22 p32)
          l22 (list p32 p42 p52)
          l32 (list p72 p62 p52)
          l42 (list p12 p82 p72)
    )
    (kyns l12 l22 l32 l42)
```

Входные данные это, опорные точки кривых Безье 2 порядка. По формуле Кунса, строится поверхности. Сетки поверхностей должны стыковаться друг с другом, но почему-то точки одной поверхности залетают на другую поверхность, притом каждый раз в других точках.

Comment: Что строит, что не правильно, как должно быть правильно, каковы входные данные?

Comment: @Cerbo, добавил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось код работает исправно, проблема была в настройках AutoCad.
Для корректной роботы загруженных программ написанных на Lisp нужно отключить функцию "Snap cursor to 2D reference points".
Для выключения  функции, перед постройкой объектов введите команду:

```
(command "osnap" "off")
```

Робота программы с включенной функцией (рисунок 1).
[image: Робота программы с включенной функцией]
Робота программы с выключенной функцией (рисунок 2).
[image: Робота программы с выключенной функцией.]